# Is it safe to store twitter access tokens client side?

Tags: security, twitter, oauth

After the Twitter oauth process, once I finally get my access_token_key and access_token_secret is it safe to store these in a javascript variable client side?

As far as I can work out nothing can be done with these keys without the consumer_key/consumer_secret?

Comment: belongs on security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe yes, because anyway client already know about access token on oauth authentication process(as a part of redirected URL).
(And, at the same time, it is always safe to have as little information as possible...)